# RefineryCMS Custom Layout Template works in host app but not with engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms, refinery

So I followed the [refinery guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/using-custom-view-or-layout-templates) to create a custom layout template.  I switched my about page to use my new template in the advanced options and it worked like a charm.

Then I created a new engine called clients and selected the new template in the advanced options of the clients page, which as you know defaults to clients - index.html.erb.

But the engine ignores my template.  Why?  I know I set it up correctly because it works in about page.  The difference is that the about page is not part of a refinery engine and the clients page is.  I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902339/how-do-i-properly-setup-a-custom-page-layout-refinerycms-2-0-6) and have tried setting my engine's index.html.erb like so

```
<% content_for :body %>
 <ul id="clients">
   <% @things.each do |t| %>
     <li>
       <%= link_to t.name, refinery.ts_t_path(t) %>
     </li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

```
<%= render :layout => 'layouts/client' %>
```

to no avail.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: There is an issue for this in github that has been marked closed, but it seems to still be a problem.
https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/1901